# How to obtain all IloNumVar from IloModeler or IloCplex

Tags: java, cplex

we have a client who gives us a `IloModeler` and we use that to solve the optimization problem doing this:

```
IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();
cplex.setModel(IloModeler);
```

and, at the end we would like to return to the client a map with all `IloNumVar` and their value: `Map<IloNumVar, Double>`.

But the issue is: How can we obtain from the original `IloModeler` the list of all `IloNumVar` in order to see their value using the function `cplex.getValue(IloNumVar)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.util.Iterator iterator()  This method returns an iterator that
> traverses the objects in the model.

For example with the [zoo example](https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-part2-python-java-c-cc04558e49b5)

```
 IloCplex cplexBus = new IloCplex();// decision variables
 IloNumVar nbbus40 = cplexBus.numVar(0, 10000,IloNumVarType.Int,"var nbBus40"); 
 IloNumVar nbbus30 = cplexBus.numVar(0, 10000,IloNumVarType.Int,"var nbBus30");// move at least 300 kids to the zoo
 cplexBus.add(nbbus40);
 cplexBus.add(nbbus30);

 cplexBus.addGe(cplexBus.sum(cplexBus.prod(40,nbbus40), cplexBus.prod(30,nbbus30)),300);// objective : minimize cost = 500*nbbus40+400*nbBus30
 cplexBus.addMinimize(cplexBus.sum(cplexBus.prod(500,nbbus40), cplexBus.prod(400,nbbus30)));cplexBus.solve();System.out.println("nbbus40 : "  +cplexBus.getValue(nbbus40) );
  System.out.println("nbbus30 : "  +cplexBus.getValue(nbbus30) );

  java.util.Iterator it = cplexBus.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object o = it.next();
    if (o instanceof IloNumVar) {
      System.out.print("Variable :"+((IloNumVar)o).getName()+"\n");
    }
  }
```

gives

```
 [java] nbbus40 : 6.0
 [java] nbbus30 : 2.0
 [java] Variable :var nbBus40
 [java] Variable :var nbBus30
```